# Beginner Java Program-- cannot get key pressed to work

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener

I am starting out with Java and I have a problem. When people click "a" on the java applet, I want it to draw a yellow rectangle and if they press anything else it draws a black rectangle but nothing happens.

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class guitarGame extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    Timer timer = new Timer (1000, this);
    String s = "";
    char a;
    int selection;

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ae){}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ae){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ae){
        a = ae.getKeyChar();
    }

    public void init(){
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (a == a)
        {
            selection = 1;
        }
        else{
            selection = 2;
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        if (selection == 1){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
        }
        if (selection == 2){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Should (a==a) be (a=='a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything with your `KeyListener` methods. Your `ActionListener` will never be called as it hasnt been registered with any component.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ae){
   char keyChar = ae.getKeyChar();
   if (keyChar == 'a' ) {
      selection = 1;
   } else {
      selection = 2;
   }

   repaint();
}
```

Some suggestions:

- Don't call `repaint` inside `paint` - This will cause the latter to loop indefinitely
- Use `enums` rather than magic numbers for paint selection.
- Call `super.paint(g)`
- Consider using Swing which has much better performance over the old heavyweight AWT.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am starting out with Java -- thank you for the tips, the applet compiles and runs fine now